# Bing Maps V8 dispatchevent javascript not working

Tags: bing-maps, dispatchevent

When clicking on a pushpin, need to programmatically click on something else.

```
 Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(layer, 'click', function(evt){
             console.log("layerHandler");
             simulateClick();
         });
    
 function simulateClick() {
             console.log("in simulateClick");
           const event = new MouseEvent('click', {
             //view: window,
             bubbles: true,
             cancelable: false
           });
           const elem = [some div]
           console.log("elem: " + elem);
              
           elem.dispatchEvent(event);
         }
```

`simulateClick()` works great on its own, outside the `Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler` code block.

The `dispatchEvent` does not work when `simulateClick` is called from inside the `Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler` code block. I see all the console messages, but `dispatchEvent` does not work.

Have spent 3 days trying to troubleshoot. Did I do something wrong, or is this Microsoft product just buggy. This would not be the first bug I have found that I have had to spend several days to troubleshoot, only to discover that it's a Microsoft issue.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm it was because of event bubbling. My bad lol